# how to pair and calculate the rows by chron date in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below,

```
structure(list(obs = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), HHMMSS = c("13:05:54", "13:16:55", "13:28:24", "13:33:20", "13:40:29", "13:46:35", "13:54:53", "14:03:11", "14:17:13", "14:24:37", "14:30:07", "14:37:22", "14:42:11", "14:48:53", "15:01:43", "15:13:41", "15:19:17", "15:30:24", "15:51:37", "15:58:12", "16:04:25", "16:11:26", "16:16:16", "16:21:24", "09:19:30", "09:28:45", "09:36:27", "09:43:30", "09:51:36", "09:58:52"), Meastype = c("NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "re", "re", "re", "re", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "re", "re", "re", "re", "re", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "NEE", "re", "re", "re"), Plot = c("11", "11b", "11c", "12", "12b", "12c", "11", "12", "13", "14", "13", "13b", "14", "14B", "21", "22", "21", "22", "23", "24", "23", "23", "23B", "24", "31", "33", "34", "31", "33", "34"), LM.flux = c(1.50185513117574, -0.566175215606913, 2.48135640444069, -1.95914765440933, -1.93409333494673, -1.71015226211811, 7.0413933643275, 4.19224559401104, 6.22441200764669, 4.76271640033768, -1.704764705803, -1.68503296181346, -0.836688802748388, -0.277899460083418, -0.941060837663844, 0.566593612955738, 6.78320266696788, 2.44894975513562, 3.313743626086, 4.49871951303632, 3.0046712012342, -0.253729057793534, -0.295953593124379, -1.95566479325521, -1.88708941334132, -3.92679880777268, -0.946583109721084, 1.93406326381689, 4.53766548724328, 2.52193436931408), dts = structure(c(18408, 18408,18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18408, 18409, 18409, 18409, 18409, 18409, 18409), format = c(dates = "m/d/y", times = "h:m:s"), origin = c(month = 1, day = 1, year = 1970), class = c("dates", "times"))), row.names = c("1", "89", "176", "263", "351", "439", "527", "641", "758", "874", "992", "1065", "1148", "1232", "1317", "1404", "1491", "1606", "1724", "1841", "1959", "2063", "2149", "2236", "11", "88", "1761", "264", "380", "498"), class = "data.frame")
```

Firstly, I want to find the NEE and RE/re data within the same date(dts). Then pair them within the same Plot number. Finally, add rows called GPP (GPP=NEE-re)at the end of each day.

I felt that's kind of complicated. How realize this?

To be clear, my expected output is like below,

```
      obs  HHMMSS   Meastype Plot   LM.flux  dts
1      1 13:05:54      NEE   11  1.5018551 05/26/20
89     2 13:16:55      NEE  11b -0.5661752 05/26/20 (no match discard)
176    3 13:28:24      NEE  11c  2.4813564 05/26/20 (no match discard)
263    4 13:33:20      NEE   12 -1.9591477 05/26/20
351    5 13:40:29      NEE  12b -1.9340933 05/26/20  (no match discard)
439    6 13:46:35      NEE  12c -1.7101523 05/26/20  (no match discard)
527    7 13:54:53       re   11  7.0413934 05/26/20
641    8 14:03:11       re   12  4.1922456 05/26/20
758    9 14:17:13       re   13  6.2244120 05/26/20
874   10 14:24:37       re   14  4.7627164 05/26/20
992   11 14:30:07      NEE   13 -1.7047647 05/26/20
1065  12 14:37:22      NEE  13b -1.6850330 05/26/20
1148  13 14:42:11      NEE   14 -0.8366888 05/26/20
1232  14 14:48:53      NEE  14B -0.2778995 05/26/20
1317  15 15:01:43      NEE   21 -0.9410608 05/26/20
1404  16 15:13:41      NEE   22  0.5665936 05/26/20
1491  17 15:19:17       re   21  6.7832027 05/26/20
1606  18 15:30:24       re   22  2.4489498 05/26/20
1724  19 15:51:37       re   23  3.3137436 05/26/20
1841  20 15:58:12       re   24  4.4987195 05/26/20
1959  21 16:04:25       re   23  3.0046712 05/26/20
2063  22 16:11:26      NEE   23 -0.2537291 05/26/20
2149  23 16:16:16      NEE  23B -0.2959536 05/26/20
2236  24 16:21:24      NEE   24 -1.9556648 05/26/20
                       GPP   11   =1.5018551-7.0413934  05/26/20
hhmmss=mean(NEE+re)    GPP   12   =1.9591477-4.1922456  05/26/20
                       GPP   13   =-1.7047647-6.2244120   05/26/20
......


11     1 09:19:30      NEE   31 -1.8870894 05/27/20
88     2 09:28:45      NEE   33 -3.9267988 05/27/20
1761   3 09:36:27      NEE   34 -0.9465831 05/27/20
264    4 09:43:30       re   31  1.9340633 05/27/20
380    5 09:51:36       re   33  4.5376655 05/27/20
498    6 09:58:52       re   34  2.5219344 05/27/20
                       GPP   31  =-1.8870894-1.9340633   05/27/20
hhmmss=mean(NEE+re)    GPP   33  =-3.9267988-4.5376655   05/27/20
                       GPP   34  =-0.9465831-2.5219344   05/27/20
```

Comment: This is not clear to me. Can you include your expected output given this sample data?

Comment: @r2evans I have edited the expected output.

Comment: What do you want to do with Plot 23, which has multiple `re` entries for 5/26/20?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with duplicates, e.g. obs 19 + 21 seem to both be `re`/`23`/`05/27/20` but with different `LM.flux`.

Here I assumed we should take the first one.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data %>%
  select(dts, Plot, Meastype, LM.flux) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Meastype, 
              values_from = LM.flux,
              values_fn = list(LM.flux = first)) %>%
  na.omit()
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 11 x 4
   dts     Plot     NEE    re
   <dates> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 18408   11     1.50   7.04
 2 18408   12    -1.96   4.19
 3 18408   13    -1.70   6.22
 4 18408   14    -0.837  4.76
 5 18408   21    -0.941  6.78
 6 18408   22     0.567  2.45
 7 18408   23    -0.254  3.31
 8 18408   24    -1.96   4.50
 9 18409   31    -1.89   1.93
10 18409   33    -3.93   4.54
11 18409   34    -0.947  2.52
```

Comment: I was wondering, how to change the code if I want to choose the biggest LM. flux, not the first one?